# Snowflake timestamp with timezone conversion issues

Tags: timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a select sql in stored procedure that gets timestamp in the format- `'Mon May 23 2022 07:00:13 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)'`

Can someone please let me know how to convert this to 2022-05-23 07:00:13.858 -0700 instead? This is how it is stored in snowflake.account_usage.task_history view. When I run select on this view, it is converting it to above Mon May 23.. format!
I am thinking I could do something like this but this isn't accurate though

```
select to_timestamp(REPLACE(replace('Mon May 16 2022 07:00:13 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)','GMT-'), '(Pacific Daylight Time)',' '),'DY MON DD YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF3 FFFF');
```

Comment: your stored procedure is in Javascript, and the date is being presented using the javascript formatting rules. pull the value from the table/view `date::text` so you get the value back already is string, thus when you compose the values into you net block of SQL it's correct.

Comment: see this doc's on a snowflake object to handle timestamps correctly, but I tend to stick to strings https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-api.html#label-sfdate